# How to display "create Site" command link in the web part?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need help to know that how can I display the "create Site" link in the webpart rather in the site Actions?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own, and link it to:

```
http://<domain>/<folder>/<folder>/_layouts/newsbweb.aspx
```